# SqL stored procedure to find the dates,month and days

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQL Server how to write the query to get the month in between the startdate and enddate, days(in month) for the Month , actual number of days in the month

startdate and enddate is passed as a input parameter , i need to know the number of months, actual days and the count of days in the month

e.g :

```
Start date : 2012-04-02
End date :   2012-08-23
```

i need to get the result as,

```
Month      Days     ActualDays _ inMonth    
----------------------------------------------
04         29       30   - (The no of days on Apr'12 )
05         31       31    
06         31       31    
07         31       31    
08         31       31
```

04  -month
29 -(Frm startdate 2-Apr to till 30-Apr'12(Apr End))
30   - (The no of days on Apr'12 )

Comment: Tip: adding *pls help..very urgent* will usually not help your question, and will sometimes hurt it

Comment: What if the dates span a new year? Your output will not tell you which year a month is for...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a procedure to calculate the number of days in a month.  I do not know what you mean by "actual days" or how that could be different.

```
if object_id('spMonthList') is not null
    drop procedure spMonthList
go
create procedure dbo.spMonthList(
    @start date
,   @end date)
as
; with  Months as
        (
        select  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @start), 0) as MonthStart
        union all
        select  dateadd(month, 1, MonthStart)
        from    Months
        where   MonthStart < @end
        )
select  datepart(month, MonthStart) as Month
,       datediff(day, MonthStart, dateadd(month, 1, MonthStart)) as NumberOfDays
from    Months;
go
exec spMonthList '2012-04-01', '2012-08-01'
```

-->

```
Month  NumberOfDays
4      30
5      31
6      30
7      31
8      31
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/463/0)